# TransientObjectException

Tags: hibernate, spring

```
Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int addressid;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID",nullable = true,insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private City city = new City();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DISTRICT_ID",nullable = true,insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private District district = new District();
}
```

Hi there, 
I have a class called Address and I cannot save this class in hibernate with DISTRICT_ID = null.

The error is

org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: form.District

I just don't know what I am missing....

Comment: Please post the code for the class District and perhaps the code where you are trying to save. It will help us figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider having city_id and city_name in the same object and if you want the City and District table to be read only then you don't your city and district to be persisted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `district` to be `null`, it should be actually `null` rather than pointing to the new transient instance:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DISTRICT_ID",nullable = true,insertable=false, updatable=false)     
private District district = null;
```

Comment: no I don't want it to be null I want DISTRICT_ID to be null which is null when it is inserted. When it is not null it works fine

Comment: I think the issue is that it isn't actually set to null. You by default set it to a new instance with `new District()`. In all likelihood this never gets saved and is therefore known as a Transient object since its not persisted. Since the Address references this transient object you are not allowed to persist.

Comment: @Gary: DISTRICT_ID is based on the district instance's @ID so unless that is null then DISTRICT_ID will always be non-null. Also since ints are not nullable you might want to use `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

Is District annotated with `@Entity`?
You probably need to specify `cascade` on `@OneToOne`
Example: `@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})`

Comment: Yes it is. What does CascadeType.PERSIST do? It didnt work either. What I want to do is to assign null value to district id sometimes.

Comment: It persists the District entity. You create a new destrict entity and assign it to Address.district and persist address. If district is not null, it must be persisted as well. This is the reason why you get the exception. If you cascade persist, district will be also persisted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save District with null DISTRICT_ID you can't use it as primary key and consequently you can't annotate it with @Id. You will have to choose different id for the District entity.